# Windows Server 2022 stops resolving domain names - unsure how to troubleshoot

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2022

Recently my Windows Server 2022 Standard installation has been having issues connecting to anything that has a domain name,seemingly at random.  Direct IP addresses are fine but anything with a proper domain name just won't connect.  This means all website address kick back DNS errors but also trying to send mail through gmail via smtp.gmail.com fails.

This is a baremetal server in a center and never had issues until recently and there doesn't seem to be a specific time when it happens.   The only way to fix the issue at the moment that I know of is to do a full system reboot which is less than ideal.

Can anyone point me in the right direct to start troubleshooting this issue?  I suspect it is something like the DNS server not working but I don't know where to look for this or what logs to be checking or how to reproduce the issue.

We have Avast Business Security setup and it is using the stock "server" profile so I don't know if there is something with that would trigger some sort DNS shut down?

Any help in where to at least start looking or if you have had this issue before and know the solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you done basic steps like checking dns settings, verify if the network profile is changed, has an additional interface which has a invalid dns etc.? what output does nslookup says?

Comment: Yes.  Nothing has changed in the last year other than a different antivirus a few months ago which shouldn't have the ability to completely block access to the DNS server...but it is my next step to remove it at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add a additional dns server in the configuration of your network adapter.A public resolver from  cloudflare for example. (1.1.1.1 from cloudflare has been measured to be the fastest DNS resolver available).
But this would only help when you don't need to resolve dns records which are on an internal network.

The cloudflare dns server is very reliable, so if you still have issues then it's something on the server

Comment: I have added in the cloudflare as my secondary DNS now.  The biggiest issue is that when it happens, I usually don't have time to properly run any tests or see whats up because someone else higher up than me has rebooted the server because they need to work.